# Downloading music from http

Tags: python, download, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Noob here, let's say I want to download a .mp3 file from a website like youtube.com or hypem.com. How do I go about it ? I know how to open a webpage (with requests) , how to parse it (with beautiful soup).  But after these step, I really don't know what to do.  How do you find de SOURCE of the file ?

Let's say for exemple this script : https://github.com/fzakaria/HypeScript/blob/master/hypeme.py

I undertand most of it except this part,

```
    serve_url = "http://hypem.com/serve/source/{}/{}".format(id, key)
    request = urllib2.Request(serve_url, "" , {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
    request.add_header('cookie', cookie)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    song_data_json = response.read()
    response.close()
    song_data = json.loads(song_data_json)
    url = song_data[u"url"]
```

First, how did he find that this url would serve the song ?

```
"http://hypem.com/serve/source/{}/{}".format(id, key)
```

Then there is this line, no idea what it is for:

```
request = urllib2.Request(serve_url, "" , {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
```

So my question, where do you find the link or information to download a file if it's not meant to download? (ex: youtube)  How do you find de SOURCE of the file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question, web scraping involves a lot of reverse engineering. I'm guessing whoever wrote the script, studied the site they were scrape and figured out what the urls for the songs look like.

As for your second question, basically, a `Request` object is being built before opening the url in order to add custom headers (`Content-Type`) to the request.

General, un-asked for advice, have a look at the [requests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests) library. This is **MUCH** simpler to use than urllib. The above code using requests would become:

```
import requests

serve_url = "http://hypem.com/serve/source/{}/{}".format(id, key)
# cookies is a simple key/value dictionary
response = requests.get(serve_url, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, cookies=cookies)
song_data = response.json()
url = song_data[u"url"]
```

Much cleaner and simpler to understand IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, will take a look. I've come accross "fiddler". With it, i've been able to see from where the file was serve. Is there  any other way to find it ?